# Trying to refresh automatically generated (but outdated) link text doesn't work

Tags: bug, question-links

Steps to reproduce:

1. Put a link to another question in a post. The title will automatically be fetched and used as link text.
2. Go to the linked post and update the title.
3. Go back to the post with the link.
4. The link text is now outdated. This is unfortunate, but I suppose this is by design.
5. You now try to update the link text so that it reflects the new title. You hit 'edit' on the post. The new updated question title is fetched immediately and the preview looks good.
6. Hit 'save'.
7. The update did not take effect. Presumably because the post source wasn't changed.

This is a bit confusing, because the preview upon hitting save looks good and does indeed show the updated title, but after saving the post, the old title is still shown.

Comment: You can usually find a way to add a blank somewhere that won't damage the post, can't you?  Then the update takes effect, doesn't it?

Comment: I assume that would work. I still think this is a bug though.

Comment: Yeah, the preview replacement is done client-side and the final server-side replacement happens after submit... and after we compare the Markdown revisions. Not sure there's a graceful way to fix this off the top of my head, would have to look.

Comment: Perhaps one could add an extra check to see if the markdown contains a network link? Such link regex presumably already exists, since there is an automatic replacement mechanism.

Comment: @Adam Generate what you'd put in the cache.  Compare that, instead of the markdown source?

Comment: Well, yeah. :P However, right now none of the post-processing on generated HTML (link replacement is one of the steps there) runs when the revisions are identical. I don't think it's a good idea to do extra work on every save with no changes just in case a question title happened to change. The odds are too low and the title lookup isn't free, nevermind all the other processing. The fact that the preview doesn't match the result is a bummer, though.

Comment: @Adam, it's presumably relatively rare to click edit, don't do any edits, then save. I doubt the extra work performed in these cases will have a measurable performance impact. Besides, the workaround is to add a space to the end of the post, which obviously triggers these steps anyway.